# Formatting enumerate tags

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

How can I parenthesize the item numbers in enumerate when I am manually entering them? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[25-1] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[25-8] Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I would like for it to display (25-1) and (25-8) automatically, i.e. I don't want to have to manually enter the parentheses every time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by this question, this appears to work fine?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(25-1)] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[(25-8)] Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you clarify, I'll take another look at it...

---

`enumitem` doesn't seem to have an option for this built in because the brackets override the formatting, so here's a bit of a workaround that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pitem}[1]{\item[(#1)]}

\begin{enumerate}
\pitem{25-1} Compute $1 + 1$
\pitem{25-8} Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Just replace all `\item` commands with the `\pitem` command.

Comment: As in, automatically add the parentheses. I'll make the appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently set up to only auto-add parens if the optional argument is used.  That could be easily modified (for example, adding `[label={(\arabic*.)}]` after the `\begin{enumerate}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\svitem\item
\renewcommand\item[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\svitem\else\svitem[(#1)]\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Normal item
\item[25-1] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[25-8] Compute $1 \times 1$
\item Another normal item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]